# Magento site redirected to localhost from live server

Tags: php, magento

I have changed

- app/etc/local.xml file
- database table core_config_data  web/unsecure/base_url path value and web/secure/base_url path value
- Removed /var/cache
- Removed /var/session
- Removed /var/tmp
- No redirect code in .htaccess file.

but still I am getting redirect issue with my magento site. Please help me.

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

Try emptying your web browser cache or even try another web browser. Some redirects are cached in browsers.

Comment: already clear my browser's cache and also try in another browser but still having the same problem